# Exercise on Dynkin Systems.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification

Currently I try to solve the following exercise:

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a < b$ and let $\mu,\nu$ be two positive, finite measures on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ such that for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a < b$ one has
$$
\mu(a,b) \leq \nu(a,b).
$$
Prove that $\mu(A) \leq \nu(A)$ for all $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ using the Dynkin-lemma.

**Question**: Why is the Dynkin-lemma necessary to solve this exercise?

**Idea:**
Consider the following set
$$
\mathcal{F}=\{A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) : \mu(A) \leq \nu(A) \};
$$
the idea would be to prove that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathcal{F}$, then we are done. But since $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is generated by $G = \{(a,b) : a < b\}$, don't we automatically have the following inclusion:
$$
\sigma(G) = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq \mathcal{F},
$$
such that the Dynkin-lemma is unnecassary here.

Comment: Where is the exercise from?

Comment: @Snoop it was giving by a friend of mine from an old problem sheet that I just do for practice.

Comment: @a.s.graduatestudent have you solved it using Dynkin systems and $\pi$-systems?

Comment: @Snoop Actually thinking about it, I am not sure this is a way to go, since $\mathcal{F}$ is not closed taking the complement right? Is there a way to save this exercise?

Comment: indeed, I had a try too and something seemed to me off with the exercise. You may save it [by setting $\mu(a,b)=\nu(a,b)$](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Uniqueness_of_Measures).

Comment: @Snoop yeah that is the classical example, I wanted to try out if one can twist this statement a bit, i.e. proving that the inequality on the open intervals sufficies to establish the inequality for all $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. But currently I don't know, which Dynkin System to choose, do you have an idea?

Comment: @Snoop I thought more about it and believe that this exercise is ill poised, take two porbability measures on [0,1] such that $\mu(1/2,1) \leq  \nu(1,2)$ for example then taking the complement the assumption ends in a contradiction with itself, hence is ill posed.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, we indeed have $G\subset \mathcal F$ hence $\sigma(G)\subset \sigma(\mathcal F)$ and since $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ is generated by $G$, the inclusion $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\subset \sigma(\mathcal F)$ but it is not clear that that $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\subset  \mathcal F $, which is precisely the role of Dynkin's lemma.

Comment: Thanks for the very quick answer, let me try to rephrase your answer, basically our goal is to establish $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) = \sigma(G) = \lambda (\mathcal{G}) \subset \mathcal{F}$ (where the last inclusion follows by definition of $\mathcal{F}$ and the assumption). For the middle equality we use Dynkin's lemma (clearly $G$ is a $\pi$-system).